# tetgen library- tetrahedralize without convex hull

Tags: convex-hull, convex, tetrahedra, tetgen

I am trying to tetrahedralize my mesh using tetgen library. However it creates convexhull on the mesh like in the picture. How can I tetrahedralize my mesh while preserving boundary surface of the mesh using tetgen library?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem. Setting the parameter `plc` as `1` fixes the problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! You helped me fix a problem that I was having as well.